# When setting up https for youtrack: "Port in base URL doesn't match with secure listen port"

Tags: ssl, https, settings, youtrack

I'm trying to set up TLS for YouTrack.

- my host port: 10088
- port inside youtrack container: 8080

I successfully set up http, but when setting up https, the installer displays a message: "Port in base URL doesn't match with secure listen port".
Why is this message displayed and how can I change the internal port in the container, which is 8080 by default?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you use Docker. In general, your approach is correct, yet there's [a known YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/BND-1834) when setting up TLS in Docker when mapped ports differ. As of now, the web UI has a validation check for the base URL and listen port when setting up TLS. It works for all the cases except when your mapped host and Docker ports are different, e.g., "10088:8080".

The solution is to map the same ports: 10088:10088, then you'll be able to enter the same port in both base URL and listen port fields.